# Woocommerce: Use different CSS for different product variations

Tags: css, woocommerce

how can I make it possible to trigger different CSS styles when clicking on different product variations?

My problem:
I have some products with varations (color or style). And for those I have added additional images to show them better. The problem is that Woocommerce handles it very well when ALL product variations have the same number of additional images. But if one variations has 1 additional image and another variation has 2 additional images I have a refresh problem. Means that if I click on a variation where I see 2 additional images and afterwards I click on a variation that has only 1 additional image, it refreshes only the 1st one and leaves the 2nd image unchanged. Means that I have a mix of correct images and a 'clicked before' image.
Xtemos, the Woodmart Theme Author, tells that this is the woocommerce standard behaviour. I don't know.
I think that I can resolve it if I add to the variations that have only 1 additional image a CSS code that will hide the 2nd (wrong) image, it would be fine for me. But I need to know how to trigger that custom CSS code only for that variation in Woocommerce.

Thank you for help

At the moment is not possible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.